# WCF methods Accessibility for different user

Tags: c#, wcf

We have 4 methods (A, B, C, D) in our service contract; now we have to show A & B method to user1 on client side & C , D method to user2.

How we can achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest not messing with contracts but rather, using authorization. In other words, let everyone see the same contract but restrict access to individual methods depending on WHO calls your service (which user, which role).

There are dozen of ways to authenticate/authorize WCFs and you probably need to research this for your own and then possibly you could come back with specific questions.